# Java ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource()) returns null

Tags: java, image, ubuntu, resources

The line

```
andImg = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("gate_and.png"));
```

fails with

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
```

I'm using Eclipse and in the navigation view under the bin folder there is the file gate_and.png, suggesting that the file is in the build path.

In the package explorer view I have

```
project/src/view/class  - This is the class that has the code above.
```

and

```
project/images/gate_and.png
```

I right clicked the project folder > build path > link source to add the images folder as a source, doing this again provides a confirmation msg that says images is already in the source.

I have also tried changing gate_and.png to images/gate_and.png and /images/gate_and.png, but since the image gate_and.png is in the bin folder, I think the original is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your class is in package `view.random.name`, then

```
getClass().getResource("gate_and.png")
```

will look for the resource in

```
/view/random/name/gate_and.png
```

relative to the root of the classpath. You apparently don't have a resource by that name there.

By setting `project/images` as a build path entry, Eclipse will include everything in it on the classpath. Therefore, your resource will appear at

```
/gate_and.png
```

You can access it with

```
getClass().getResource("/gate_and.png")
```

Note the leading `/` that means *start looking at the root of the classpath*, ie. it's an absolute path.

All these rules are explained in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29).